# Generating links with <span> and <h3> embedded using anchor in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I am using CodeIgniter's anchor tag to generate links

Here's the code I am using in my view :

```
<?=anchor('blog/post/'.$row->id,$row->title);?>
```

Above code is rendering the url like

```
<a href="http://localhost/Blog/index.php/blog/post/3">Title</a>
```

I wanted to know other ways to embed other HTML elements within `<a>` tags ?

Output on HTML page should look like :

```
<a href="link" rel="bookmark"> 
    <span class="location">Category</span>
     <h3 class="headline">Headline</h3>
     <span class="new">New !</span>
    <span class="date">Date</span>
  </a>
```

ie. within `<a>` tags I want to embed `<span>` and `<h3>`

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the second parameter of the anchor method, like this:

```
$a ='<span class="location">Category</span>
     <h3 class="headline">Headline</h3>
     <span class="new">New !</span>
    <span class="date">Date</span>';

<?=anchor('blog/post/'.$row->id,$a.$row->title,array("rel" => "bookmark"));?>
```

Additionaly I added a third parameter which lets you write the html attributes for the  tags like; in this case, the 'rel' attribute.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, CodeIgniter's html helper + some functions included in the url helper are absolute overkill.

Just use vanilla HTML with PHP short tags... it conveys better semantics, saves CPU, and will be easier to understand for folks inheriting your code in the future...

```
<a href="blog/post/<?= $row->id; ?>" rel="bookmark"> 
    <span class="location">Category</span>
     <h3 class="headline"><?= $row->title; ?></h3>
     <span class="new">New !</span>
    <span class="date">Date</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $my_a = '<span class="location">Category</span>
        <h3 class="headline">'.$row->title.'</h3>
        <span class="new">New !</span>
        <span class="date">Date</span>';
    anchor('blog/post/'.$row->id,$row->title);?>
```

Or write your own helper for this type of links.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing the HTML yourself and just using the `site_url()` function instead to generate the link href.

`anchor()` is meant for simple links and embedding links in templates without writing HTML. The way you want to output the link is not what `anchor()` was designed to do.

You could create a helper with a function like this:

```
function bookmark_anchor($uri, $text)
{
    $html  = '<a href="' . site_url($uri) . '" rel="bookmark">';
    $html .= '<span class="location">Category</span>';
    $html .= '<h3 class="headline">' . $text . '</h3>';
    $html .= '<span class="new">New !</span>';
    $html .= '</a>';

    return $html
}
```

And then use it as such:

```
<?php echo bookmark_anchor('blog/post/'.$row->id, $row->title); ?>
```

*Sidenote*: I'd avoid using PHP short tags if you can stand it. They're not instantly portable to every system, so you might run into issues if you move your code to another server (and you might not be able to enable short tags). CI offers an option to rewrite short tags for you, but that introduces overhead via output buffering.